# Which browsers support document.activeElement?

Tags: javascript, browser, focus

Which web browsers / versions have support for `document.activeElement`?

This property lets you see which element is active / has focus.

Are there any main gotchas/difference between implementations?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

document.activeElement is supported by IE6+, FF3+, Safari 4+, Opera 9+, Chrome 9+. (FF2, Saf3 don't support this property)

Comment: Where do you find out such things, except on Stack Overflow? I didn't find this on quirksmode or MDN.

Comment: You can find it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.activeElement#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Opera 9.6+ (not 9+), Chrome 2+ (the same WebKit version 530 as in Safari 4)

Comment: Found this helpful site: http://caniuse.com/ but unfortunately does not have an entry for activeElement.

Answer (score 1):

It still doesn't work on WebKit based browsers in **xhtml page**
see https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63922