# Adding simple condition with jQuery to see if input is focused?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set a simple condition inside the loop so that the code inside is only run if any input is focused or if any element in the body is focused. How do I do each thing?

```
setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById('clickMe').style.display= "block";  
}, 1000 );
```

thanks

Comment: Have a look at some of the [other posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483741/how-to-determine-which-html-page-element-has-focus) about how to determine where the focus is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the W3C [document.activeElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#dom-document-activeelement) proprety to see which element is focused (also documented at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.activeElement)).

Note that this property is introduced in HTML5 and may not be widely implemented, so test for support and expect it not to be supported in a reasonable percentage of clients.

Comment: I thought there was a simple solution with js. Isn't there? I'd rather do something that works in all browsers

Comment: What RobG posted _is_ the simple solution. If you want it to work in _all_ browsers (including what, Netscape? IE5?) it gets more complicated.

Comment: The SO post [Which browsers support document.activeElement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318415/which-browsers-support-document-activeelement) might be of interest.