# Test if any input has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building something with keyboard shortcuts e.g. you press Ctrl+m to open a menu. I use jQuery and the jwerty plugin for that, this looks like the following code:

```
jwerty.key('m', function () {
    toggleMenu();
});
```

Tapping the "m" key triggers the toggleMenu function.

Now I was wondering how to prevent this function from being triggered while a user is typing in an input field or textarea.

Comment: I found this in [documentation](https://github.com/keithamus/jwerty) in Git. _If you're binding to a selector and don't need the context, you can ommit it: 
`jwerty.key('⌃+⇧+P/⌘+⇧+P', function () { [...] }, 'input.email', '#myForm');`_ Give it a try and let us know.

Comment: function  toggleMenu(){alert('ok');} jwerty.key('m', toggleMenu, "body:not(input)"); this should work but doesn't as it fires even in the input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never used jwerty, but I'd suggest:

```
jwerty.key('m', function (e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'input') {
        toggleMenu();
    }
});
```

This tests the target of the event, and, if it's *not* an `input`, calls the `toggleMenu()` function; if it *is* an `input`, it does nothing (though you could explicitly `return false` if you'd prefer).

To account for `textarea`, as I really should have done, the above could be extended (to add another clause to the `if` assessment, or the following, `switch`-based approach could be taken:

```
jwerty.key('m', function (e) {
    switch (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'input':
        case 'textarea':
            break;
        default:
            toggleMenu();
            break;
    }
});
```

If the target-element is either an `input` or `textarea`, pressing `m` does nothing, whereas if *not* either of those two elements the default state is entered and `toggleMenu()` is called.

Comment: Don't forget about `textarea`

Comment: I also accounted for select in my new code based on this since you can use 'm' to go to an item that starts with 'm' e.g. 'monaco'. Thanks!

Comment: `if (/[^input|textarea|select]/i.test(e.target.tagName)) {` this would also work [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dL6an/)

Comment: that's clever and much shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the active element is the body element. If it is, no inputs are focused.

```
var nothingIsFocused = document.activeElement === document.body

if (nothingIsFocused) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add another event handler on your inputs and textareas which calls `event.stopPropagation()` (or if you use jQuery, `return false`).  That way that event handler will get triggered first, and it will prevent the event from "propagating" up to your existing handler.

Another option would be to check the event inside your existing handler to see if it came from an input/textarea (see the other answers if you want to take this approach; if you care about (really) old browser backward comparability you'll want to use David's answer, as activeElement isn't supported by old browsers: [Which browsers support document.activeElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318415/which-browsers-support-document-activeelement)).

Comment: Older than IE4? [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:focus` selector provided by jQuery (and some browsers) and the `is` function to test if an item has focus:

```
$(".my-thing").is(':focus')
```

Comment: This does the opposite, I want to check whether nothing is in focus

Comment: Slightly off topic, but this doesn't seem to work in PhantomJS